# Dynamic Wordpress Admin Panel

Tags: admin, wp-admin

I would like to create a customized Wordpress admin panel that changes based on the user's log in credentials.

For example, if the site administrator logs in from the WP-Admin page, they would be directed to a full suite of administrative options in their admin view.

If User Type A logs in from the WP-Admin page, they would see a limited set of custom options in their admin panel. User Type B would see a different set of admin option from Type A, and so on...

How can I create a dynamic WP-admin panel using Wordpress?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress admin pages are typically created using [`add_menu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) function that takes care of menu entry and calls custom function (provided by you) to generate content of the page.

Obviously content of the page is arbitrary and should be easy to modify conditionally, using [`current_user_can()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) or other necessary checks.